# instalé reacstrap y bootstrap, pero al hacer run start para mostrar en pantalla me sale error

Tags: reactjs, npm, reactstrap

---

Esto me salio despues de tener el package.json pero creo que es un error de sintaxis

```
C:\Users\Roy\Downloads\ReactEj>npm start

> ReactEj@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Roy\Downloads\ReactEj
> node App.js

(node:2976) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in 
the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was 
created)
C:\Users\Roy\Downloads\ReactEj\App.js:1
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^
```

como puedo importar dentro de un modulo?

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ReactEj@1.0.0 start: `node App.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
```

como seria una salida de registro adicional?

```
npm ERR! Failed at the ReactEj@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esto se puede debe a que no encuentra el `package.json` en la raíz de tu proyecto al dar `npm start` (no es necesario el `run` dentro del comando cuando ejecutas start), asegúrate de que esté el `package.json` y ahí instalas todo.

En caso de que no te sirva podrías buscar el `complete log` y pegarlo aquí en la pregunta, la ruta que te mostró el log es en `C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-10-12T15_44_39_098Z-debug.log`

Comment: en mi carpeta tengo el archivo "package-lock.json". no es el mismo?

Comment: nop, debes tener ambos, el `package.json` y el `package-lock.json`, tal ves lo borraste por error, ¿creaste correctamente el proyecto cierto?

Comment: si, supongo, hice el mismo proceso que decia el tutorial xd, solo que cuando iba a mostrar la "app" me tiro ese error

Comment: pudiste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes algo de código escrito, el `package-lock.json` y el `node_modules` con los módulos instalados te recomiendo en consola escribir en la raiz del proyecto `npm init --yes`, esto para generar un `package.json` automáticamente con los módulos que tenías, luego para iniciar con `npm start` debes dejar en  en el `package.json` dentro de "scripts" lo siguiente o con igual a esto:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node index.js",
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

Puede ser `index.js` o tu carpeta `src` donde tengas todo el proyecto, eso depende de ti.

Comment: Bueno, ahora me tira otro error

Comment: ¿me podrías indicar cuál es?

Comment: si, lo puse arriba "Esto me salio despues de tener el package.json pero creo que es un error de sintaxis"

Answer (score 0):

Mira esta otra pregunta con respuestas a el mismo error y formas de solucionarlo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63588714/node9374-warning-to-load-an-es-module-set-type-module

Por si estas siguiendo un tutorial te recomiendo buscar uno bien actualizado o hace menos tiempo, ya que sobretodo en Javascript con React lo necesitarás.

Comment: ok muchas gracias @Abraham